# how to display the last image of a file without knowing the name of the image <IMG SRC

Tags: html, image, src

I have an FTP server with 3 kind of photos:

```
a) the photos called c001, c002 ...
b) the photos called f001, f002 ...
c) the phots called 000abcd_date_time_ramdomnumber
```

I display in my website the first two with  IMG SRC="c001.jpg"   etc.

I would like to do the same with the third one displaying for instance the last 3,  but I do not know how to do it

thanks for the advice - renato

Comment: Without knowing the exact name of the resource, you'll need to add server-side code to find the image first.

Comment: `ramdomnumber` is the problem rest the date and time you can call with coding . You need to find the way to get the `ramdomnumber` variable