# Display image with wildcard in src

Tags: html

I have a series of photos on a server with a strict naming convention: "uniqueId-readableName.jpg". I do this because my website database currently only logs the uniqueID (and some unrelated info), but people occasionally need to look at the file server directly to browse the photos (via FTP) so a readable name is useful. For example

```
001456-War Horse.jpg
003295-Sunshine Daiseys.jpg
129084-Laboring at the farm 2013-08-11.jpg
```

Now, I'm fairly sure the best option would be to set up the database with a record of the full file names, but I just wanted to see if anyone had any ideas I may have missed. [This question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767791/how-to-display-the-last-image-of-a-file-without-knowing-the-name-of-the-image-i) is similar, but here I have strict naming conventions - not sure if that opens up any possibilities or not.

I'm applying this to `img`, but the same idea could be appled to any file extension (eg, download "789-My Homework.zip" or "123-Family vacation.zip").

As an example of what I'm looking for, in Windows Explorer you can do a file search for

```
0*.jpg
```

and all of the following files can be returned

```
001456-War Horse.jpg
003295-Sunshine Daiseys.jpg
029084-Laboring at the farm 2013-08-11.jpg
```

In my case the beginning part is always unique, so I'd like to use something like `001456-*.jpg` and have it return `001456-War Horse.jpg`.

Is there any way do this on a website?

```
<img src="001456-*.jpg" />
```

Comment: you want to do this using html ? cause regex can helps you or a query in your database

Comment: @FaceOfJock: how can regex in a HTML file access your filesystem? Also I'm pretty sure the OP made it clear he does not want to keep a mapping in his Database.

Comment: @sunny R Gupta regex using php not using html

Comment: Oh, that is what I recommended in my answer below ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although no such method exists, you can still do a server side scripting to acheive the functionality you require.

For example in PHP you could use in-built commands to browse a folder, select all files matching the criteria name as '001456-*.jpg' and then depending upon the number of records returned select the first filename and insert it into an IMG tag.

Here is a sample implementation in PHP:

```
$files = array();
$id = "001456";
$files = glob("id-*.jpg");

echo "<img src='$files[0]' />"; //Assuming one file is found for every unique ID.
```

Comment: A comment would have been better than a downvote. I'm all ears for anybody who hates my answer. :) Cheers!

Comment: I don't see any issue with it

Comment: To expand on this idea, if the system rendering the html does not have file access, you could easily create a rewrite rule to properly respond to requests formatted like you have in your question: `<img src="001456-*.jpg" />`. You'd have a script containing the `glob` logic above, and a rewrite that points requests that match `^\d{6}-\*\.` to the script, which would serve the matched file.

Comment: You could in fact get rid of that `foreach`, since `glob()` already returns an array, as in: `$files = glob("id-*.jpg");`

Comment: True that. :)
Modified.

Comment: This is a perfect solution for what I need, I knew there was something I was overlooking. Thanks!